# Redirect standardoutput for Microsoft hotfix

Tags: c#

im currently trying to write a dll that handles the intall of MS hotfixes via a vbscript. I have so far managed to get the core functionality working and have managed to trap the return codes but would like to go one step further - I need to trap the output from the process as the return codes are not always correct (ie. if a hotfix is not required it still returns a return code of 0 - not good).

Below is a copy of some of the code im using to start the process and write the output to the event log but it write a blank values all the time...any ideas what im doing wrong?

```
   Process p = new Process();

            p.StartInfo.FileName = strExe;
            p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

            p.Start();
            string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            p.WaitForExit();

            WriteEvent(strAppName, "Error", 1000, output);
```

Comment: Installing a hotfix silently is the very *last* thing anybody should ever consider.  Hotfixes haven't been tested like regular Microsoft releases, installing them without the user's knowledge makes it much harder to diagnose problems.

Comment: Hans, I understand what you're saying but I beg to differ. I work in a large corporate organisation with managed OS builds and this is the preferred method of deployment - this will of course go through 3 test environments before it reaches the end user for delivery.

Answer (score 2):

The hotfix might be writing to StandardError instead of StandardOutput.  Here is a method I use when I need to catch both kinds of output:

```
        /// <summary>
    /// run a program using the provided ProcessStartInfo
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="processInfo"></param>
    /// <returns>Both StandardError and StandardOutput</returns>
    public static string WithOutputRedirect(System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo processInfo)
    {
        string result = "";

        processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

        processInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

        System.Diagnostics.Process p = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(processInfo);

        p.ErrorDataReceived += delegate(object o, System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Data != null && e.Data != "")
            {
                result += e.Data + "\r\n";
            }
        };
        p.BeginErrorReadLine();

        p.OutputDataReceived += delegate(object o, System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Data != null && e.Data != "")
            {
                result += e.Data + "\r\n";
            }
        };
        p.BeginOutputReadLine();

        p.WaitForExit();

        return result;
    }
```