# Is there anyway to save the output of shell script into a text file?

Tags: c#

i have to run some executable file and how do i save the output to a text file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a command line, you can do:

```
mycommand.exe > logfile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

For sample that reads output of process using ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput and Process.BeginOutputReadLine/OutputDataReceived look here: [Redirect standardoutput for Microsoft hotfix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765379/redirect-standardoutput-for-microsoft-hotfix/5765669#5765669)